# Passing current_user from Flask-Login to Plotly Dash app

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-login

I am trying to build a Dash app which is integrated in Flask app. Everything seems to be working fine but when I try to show logged user in the Dash app it comes out as 'None'.

My app structure is as below:

```
example/
example/
  dashapp/
    static/
      custom-css.css
    templates/
      base.html
      home.html
      login.html
    __init__.py
    app1.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    routes.py
  application.py
  config.py
  users.db
```

My Dash app is in `app1.py`. I've tried several ways to pass `current_user` but no success. It comes out fine in `home.html` though. I guess the problem is with my app being in separate file and not in the `routes.py`.

Here is the code for `app.py`:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dashapp import application
from flask_login import login_required, current_user


app1 = dash.Dash(__name__, server = application, routes_pathname_prefix = '/app1/', assets_folder = 'static', assets_url_path = '/static')
app1.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app1.css.config.serve_locally = True

app1.layout = html.Div(
    children = '{}'.format(current_user)
)

for view_func in app1.server.view_functions:
    if view_func.startswith('/app1/'):
        app1.server.view_functions[view_func] = login_required(app1.server.view_functions[view_func])
```

`routes.py` code:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from dashapp import application, db
from dashapp.forms import LoginForm
from dashapp.models import User
from dashapp import app1


@application.route('/')
@application.route('/home')
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@application.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('home')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@application.route('/app1/')

@application.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Other scripts are pretty much standard and I won't include them in the question unless they are really needed.

Please suggest how to overcome my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I managed to fix this with some help. Just in case somebody gets stuck see below updated code.

Added `session` rows to store current username in `routes.py`:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, session
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from dashapp import application, db
from dashapp.forms import LoginForm
from dashapp.models import User
from dashapp import app1

@application.route('/')
@application.route('/home')
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@application.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        session['username'] = current_user.username
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['username'] = form.username.data
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('home')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@application.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('username', None)
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

And `session` in the callback for `app1.py`:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dashapp import application
from flask_login import login_required
from flask import session

app1 = dash.Dash(__name__, server = application, routes_pathname_prefix = '/app1/', assets_folder = 'static', assets_url_path = '/static')
app1.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app1.css.config.serve_locally = True

app1.layout = html.Div(
    children = [
        html.Div(id='div2'),
        html.Div(id='div3', children = 'xxxx'),
    ],
)

@app1.callback(
    Output('div2', 'children'),
    [Input('div3', 'children')])
def update_intervalCurrentTime(children):
    return session.get('username', None)

for view_func in app1.server.view_functions:
    if view_func.startswith('/app1/'):
        app1.server.view_functions[view_func] = login_required(app1.server.view_functions[view_func])
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. I guess the problem is that current user hasn't been initialised when the 'application' registers Dash app. Nice workaround, though seems a bit insecure since Flask sessions are just encoded.

https://github.com/RafaelMiquelino/dash-flask-login/blob/master/app.py - more robust solution in my opinion. It checks current_user in the callbacks and uses contents of the page as Input, so the callbacks are called on page load. You can also skip the protection of the views if user experience isn't an issue.

Here's a simplified example of how I used it:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('graph-wrapper', 'children'),
    [Input('page-content', 'children')])
def load_graph(input1):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return dcc.Graph() # Dash Graph populated with current_user data from db
    else:
        return ''
```